# Errors Running WebGoat 7 on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to run WebGoat on a standalone Tomcat7 server. I placed the "webgoat-container-7.0.1.war" in the Tomcat directory and renamed the file "WebGoat.war". The initial landing page, "http://10.1.1.1/WebGoat/" looks well, and I am able to login. However,after I login I start seeing errors and I am not able to access the lessons. Below is a screen capture of the errors that I receive.

[WebGoat Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdCZd.png)

Am I missing a dependency somewhere? What can I do to troubleshoot?

Thanks,
Brooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while myself. It's possible that you are missing permissions to write the user database file. If your log entries show something like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/UserDatabase.mv.db (Permission denied)
```

Then it would be a matter of granting your tomcat user permissions to the folder listed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/) to run the WebGoat "Easy Run" JAR. Supervisor keeps WebGoat "Easy Run"  running and starts it automatically on reboots.

Comment: Yeah, the runnable jar is very nice and convenient, glad you found a solution!

On a side note, the troubleshooting steps I followed were to look at the 'catalina.out' file for my tomcat instance, it ultimately led me to find the issue.